# Share data from view

Tags: views, 8

How can I share data from a view to an excel file. I just need a report.

Or can anyone suggest a solution from which I can extract the data from a view?

Answer (score 1):

I think [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) module is what you need.

Comment: Yes. I used it. But the csv_serialization requires a library. I followed the steps to install and it was done. But still the module is not getting activated.

Comment: Did you add it using drush?